# Why is the gnome 3 lock screen not displaying?

Tags: gnome, gui, lock-screen, appearance

I installed gnome 3 recently and was expecting the [new lock screen](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/gnomes-new-lock-screen-design-goes-online), but when I lock the screen I'm displayed with the 'old' version:

[image]

How do I get the lock screen to appear like the one displayed in the article?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213763/how-to-enable-new-lock-screen-on-gnome-3-6

That solved the problem, you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new design isn't live yet. This is design waiting for approval. Read this article more carefully.

Comment: Please include the article link.

Answer (score 1):

User already reported that the "new" lock screen is live.

[GNOME lock screen (screensaver) is missing music controls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204813/gnome-lock-screen-screensaver-is-missing-music-controls)

[How to disable sliding login screen in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207743/how-to-disable-sliding-login-screen-in-gnome-3-6)