# GNOME lock screen (screensaver) is missing music controls

Tags: gnome, screensaver, lock-screen

I have a custom Ubuntu 12.10 configuration (started out as a minimal installation of Ubuntu 12.04 with a number of other packages such as Gnome Shell selectively installed via apt-get and then upgraded to 12.10). (Almost) everything works just fine. However, the lock screen (Gnome screensaver) does not expose a UI to control music playback. Whenever I have Rhythmbox running in the background I cannot pause music playback without unlocking the screen. Obviously some package(s) or configuration bits are not present but I am not able to figure out what needs to be added or done in order to enable playback control in the lock screen.

Any idea what I might be missing? Ideally I would not like to install Ubuntu desktop only to get music controls in the Gnome lock screen.

Comment: I currently have the same issue, I reported the bug here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1073385
please mark as affecting you

Answer (score 3):

i think this should solve your problem:

execute the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-notifications true
```

this will enable notifications ( music too ) for gnome-screensaver .

( for disabling run the same command with `false` at the end! )

i found that command somewhere while i tried to fix my own problem..

**Note:** This solution on currently works for Rhythmbox and may be deployed in a later version of Gnome (3.8?) (See ref: [lock screen bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1073385/comments/8))

Comment: I tried that suggestion and it works for notifications but not for music players? Is this only available for Rhythmbox or Banshee as well?

Comment: I found the answer on the bug posting - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1073385 - this feature of music only works for Rhythmbox and not Banshee until possibly Gnome 3.8