# How to enable new lock screen on gnome 3.6?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I'm using Gnome 3.6 (PPA) on Ubuntu 12.10

But I don't get the "new" lock screen.

Users reported new lock screen are available now.

[GNOME lock screen (screensaver) is missing music controls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204813/gnome-lock-screen-screensaver-is-missing-music-controls)

[How to disable sliding login screen in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207743/how-to-disable-sliding-login-screen-in-gnome-3-6)

Is there any specific settings to be enabled to get the new lock screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

( please only try the following steps if you know how to use the terminal! )

First I would have to know if even your login-screen is old as well?

If so, maybe this will help you.

you still see the old lock/login-screen because you are still using the Ubuntu default
display manager **lightdm**, I guess..

To get the new L&F you have to set **gdm** as default-manager.
( be sure that gdm 3.6 is installed on your machine! )

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Now, you have to stop **lightdm** but this will shut down your display-manager and you will only see a terminal but that's fine.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Right after **lightdm** has stopped, login in the prompting shell and execute following

```
sudo service gdm start
```

That's it!

Comment: So awesome! thanks!
Took me hours of searching Ubuntu forums and askubuntu because google doesn't bring this question up for some reason...