# How to disable sliding login screen in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, login-screen

I am using Gnome 3.6 and I am quite annoyed by the login screen when my computer wakes up. The new implementation in Gnome includes two steps. First you have to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click and drag upward (slide), so the big clock disappears, and then enter your credentials. I am interested in removing the first part.

Comment: this is not possible at the moment, you could switch your display-manager from gdm to lightDM to get the old lock screen back.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour has been [changed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686740) since GNOME 3.8 so you can just type in your password even though you still see the screen shield. There is no need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or slide the shield.

Comment: I do, and it looks like not all the characters I typed are passed to the input. And then `esc` again and type again etc.. needs to be improved.

Comment: I tested it on GNOME 3.14 and it works as expected. But I agree with you that it needs to be improved. There's an open bug report on launchpad about it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1049645

Answer (score 0):

The following Gnome Extension disables the the screen shield:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/